# exclude array of elements from simplify function

Tags: javascript, regex

I have this function to remove everything except characters:

```
function simplify(string) {
    return string.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9'_]+/g, " ").trim();
}
```

Now I want to exclude an array of elements so that they be intact in the string.

The array is :

```
["’", "-"]
```

Now the function removes theses two elements :

```js
function simplify(string) {
    return string.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9'_]+/g, " ").trim();
}

console.log(simplify("father’s deep-day"));
```

The desired result would be :

"father’s deep-day"

Comment: You don't need `A-Z` in the regexp, since you converted the string to lowercase.

Comment: Add those characters to the character set in square brackets.

Comment: You can write a function that takes in the target string and the exclusion string `!"#$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_\`abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz{|}~`
and creates the negated class `[^a-zA-Z0-9\\!-/:-@\[\]-\`{-~]` and returns the altered target string. The alternative is to take in a subset of exclusion characters to be appended to a fixed regex. Doing any of this is difficult..

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to just add those characters in your regular expression.

```js
function simplify(string) {
    return string.toLowerCase().replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9'_’-]+/g, " ").trim();
}

console.log(simplify("father’s deep-day"));
```

---

If you want to, sometimes, pass additional characters that should be kept, you could pass them as parameters to the `simplify` function and then dynamically create the regular expression in there.

```js
function simplify(string, safeChars = []) {
  const defaultChars = ['A-Z', 'a-z', '0-9', '\'', '_'];
  const allAllowedChars = defaultChars.concat(safeChars).join('');
  const regularExpression = new RegExp(`[^${allAllowedChars}]`, 'g');
  return string.toLowerCase().replace(regularExpression, " ").trim();
}

console.log(simplify("father’s deep-day", ["’", "-"]));
```